# Javascript String argument with character reference

Tags: javascript, character-reference

I have a javascript method call with a string parameter. In the string text sometimes contains html character references, e.g. `&#39;` I am getting an unexpected identifier error. If I have the character reference as `&quot;` then it works fine. Not sure why that is. Below is a code snippet of what I am trying to do. Actual method is much longer and trying to do something different than what I show here, but this snippet should be able to reproduce the error.

```
<script>
function unescapeHTML(html) {
  var htmlNode = document.createElement("div");
  htmlNode.innerHTML = html;
  if(htmlNode.innerText)
    alert htmlNode.innerText; // IE
  else 
    alert htmlNode.textContent; // FF

}
</script>
<a class="as_Glossary" onmouseover="unescapeHTML('The manufacturer&#39;s sales in dollars to all purchasers in the United States excluding certain exemptions for a specific drug in a single calendar quarter divided by the total number of units of the drug sold by the manufacturer in that quarter'); return true;" onmouseout="hideGlossary(); return true;">Test</a>
```

When I mouseover I get the error

Comment: There is no charachter between 9 and semi-colon right?

Comment: could you maybe post the JavaScript source or at least piecs of it? This increases the time to get high-quality answers considerably ;)

Comment: Thanks Juri, I added some snippet to demonstrate the issue

Comment: @Emrah no there isn't any character between 9 and semi-colon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that your `&#39;` is being converted to a `'` before the JavaScript is evaluated. So, JavaScript sees the following (wrapped for readability):

```
unescapeHTML('The manufacturer's sales in dollars to all purchasers in 
the United States excluding certain exemptions for a specific drug in a 
single calendar quarter divided by the total number of units of the drug 
sold by the manufacturer in that quarter'); 
return true;
```

Notice how the string ends after `manufacturer`, and the rest is treaded as code, with an extra unmatched close quote `'`. You need to prefix the `'` in `manufacturer's` with a backslash in order for the string to be properly quoted in JavaScript:

```
a class="as_Glossary" onmouseover="unescapeHTML('The manufacturer\&#39;s sales...
```

You also need parentheses in your `alert` expressions:

```
function unescapeHTML(html) {
  var htmlNode = document.createElement("div");
  htmlNode.innerHTML = html;
  if(htmlNode.innerText)
    alert(htmlNode.innerText); // IE
  else 
    alert(htmlNode.textContent); // FF
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a **semi-colon** after that character reference